# Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {x^n} {a^n-b^n}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose there are the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac {x^n} {a^n-b^n}$, $\,a>b>0$.

I tried to calculate radius of convergence by
$\dfrac1R=\limsup\sqrt[n]{\dfrac 1 {a^n-b^n}}$ but could not calculate this limit.

Could you please give me some hint ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$\frac{1}{a^n - b^n} = \frac{1}{a^n\left(1-\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^n\right)}$$